# Laravel Carbon dates not getting modified in Seeder

Tags: laravel, date, parsing, php-carbon, laravel-seeding

In a Laravel Seeder, I am trying to take a `Faker` generated date, convert it to Carbon and then grab two dates that are just a few hours apart to represent a 4 hour session. For example, 
`Start Date: 03/13/2016 12:00PM`
`End Date: 03/13/2016 5:00PM`

Below is what I've landed on, but both the `$start` and `$end` variable are *always* the same.

```
            for ($k = 0; $k < $jobAssignmentCount; $k++) {
                $randomDate = $faker->dateTimeBetween($job->starts_at, '+6 months');
                $dateTime = Carbon::instance($randomDate)->minute(0)->second(0);
                $start = $dateTime;
                $end = $dateTime;
                $end->addHours(4);
                $jobAssignment = JobAssignment::create([
                    'job_id' => $job->id,
                    'starts_at' => $start,
                    'ends_at' => $end,
                    'assignment_notes' => 'Assignment Notes',
                    'is_cancelled' => $faker->boolean(10),
                    'cancelled_at' => $faker->dateTimeBetween('+6 months', '+1 year'),
                    'cancelled_by_profile_id' => $profile->id,
                    'is_billable' => $faker->boolean(75),
                ]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `$start` and `$end` to the same object, `$dateTime`. Since they're all the same object, when you change one, the other will change as well. The easiest thing will be to clone the object and then `addHours()` to the clone:

```
$start = Carbon::instance($randomDate)->minute(0)->second(0);
$end = clone $start;
$end->addHours(4);
```

Now you should have two different objects, a `$start` and an `$end`, with times that are 4 hours apart.

Comment: This one fixed my issue!

Comment: @jdcarg Great! Please consider accepting it as the answer to your question so that anyone with a similar question can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this: `$end = $end->addHours(4);` or clone it first.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I used the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because both $start and $end are referencing the same Carbon object. Try creating two different $dateTime objects - $startDateTime and $endDateTime - seeded a few hours apart and reference those to $start and $end, respectively.